# Plotting a histogram using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I am new to using argparse and in this instance I have to use it as the code will be ran through a terminal. I want the user to be able to enter a bin size in the terminal and then the program will plot the histogram. The code works fine if I use input statements however I am having problems getting it to work with argparse. Here is the code at the moment.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import sys

fh = open('dummy2.pepmasses')
values = []


for line in fh:
    data = line.split()
    protname, pep, mz, z, p, sequence = data
    mz = float(mz)
    #print(mz)
    values.append(mz)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--Bin_size', type=int, metavar='', required=True, help='Size of bin, multiple of 100 between 100-1000')

args = parser.parse_args()

def Histogram(Bin_size):
    if Bin_size ==100:
        bins = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400,                        3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4300, 4400, 4500, 4600, 4700, 4800, 4900, 5000, 5100, 5200, 5300, 5400, 5500, 5600, 5700, 5800, 5900, 6000, 6100]
    elif Bin_size ==200:
        bins = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 2400, 2600, 2800, 3000, 3200, 3400, 3600, 3800, 4000, 4200, 4400, 4600, 4800, 5000, 5200, 5400, 5600, 5800, 6000, 6200]
    elif Bin_size ==300:
        bins = [0, 300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500, 1800, 2100, 2400, 2700, 3000, 3300, 3600, 3900, 4200, 4500, 4800, 5100, 5400, 5700, 6000, 6300]
    elif Bin_size ==400:
        bins= [0, 400, 800, 1200, 1600, 2000, 2400, 2800, 3200, 3600, 4000, 4400, 4800, 5200, 5600, 6000, 6400]
    elif Bin_size ==500:
        bins = [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000, 5500, 6000, 6500]
    elif Bin_size ==600:
        bins = [0, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3000, 3600, 4200, 4800, 5400, 6000, 6600]
    elif Bin_size ==700:
        bins = [0, 700, 1400, 2100, 2800, 3500, 4100, 4900, 5600, 6300]
    elif Bin_size ==800:
        bins = [0, 800, 1600, 2400, 3200, 4000, 4800, 5600, 6400]
    elif Bin_size ==900:
        bins = [0, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 4500, 5400, 6300]
    elif Bin_size ==1000:
        bins = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000]
    else:
        print("Invalid bin size, please enter a multiple of 100 between 100-1000")
    if Bin_size ==100 or Bin_size==200 or Bin_size==300 or Bin_size==400 or Bin_size==500 or Bin_size==600 or Bin_size==700 or Bin_size==800 or Bin_size==900 or Bin_size==1000:
        plt.hist(values, bins, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
        plt.xlabel('m/z value')
        plt.ylabel('Number of proteins')
        plt.title('Histogram of mz')
        plt.legend('Bins')
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Histogram(args.Bin_size)
```

This returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project_test.py", line 54, in <module>
    Histogram(args.Bin_size)
  File "project_test.py", line 46, in Histogram
    plt.hist(values, bins, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3066, in hist
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 950, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 586, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1871, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I'm really having trouble even understanding what this error means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much about `matplotlib`, but the error message has something to do with the `tkinter` module which is usually used to create applications with GUI (as well as just to display graphics). There may be some configuration it requires that you haven't done or aren't doing.

Comment: If the value of args.Bin-size looks reasonable then problem isn't with argparse.  I suspect it's something to do with the marplotlib setup in this terminal use.

Comment: @hpaulj So maybe it's not possible plot in the terminal with matplotlib? Maybe the better option would just be to output a csv file and use other software to plot the values

Comment: This problem has absolutely nothing to do with the use of argparse. Have you done any research at all into the error `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`?